# css li flow around each other (image attached)

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on my note application and I got stuck with the layout. [Link to the screenshot of the layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqPHx.png)

Each of the boxes may have different height according to the text in the database. Each of the boxes is a LI (bootstrap span3 size).

- I need the boxes to flow around each other nicely without white spaces.
- I have seen that some webpages calculate absolute positioning in PHP for each of the boxes, but I hope I can achieve that only with CSS.

So far the structure is following:

```
<ol>
 <li class="memPersonUnit clearfix span3">
  <div class="memPersonUnitContainer clearfix">

            THE CONTENT

  </div>
 </li>
</ol>
```

The css style:

- ol has display: block;
- li has display: position: relative; float:left (inherited from SPAN3 size);
- div has border: 1px gray solid;

How should I change my css to achieve my goal?

If I need to use the PHP calculations, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't really be able to achieve that only in css unless you create individual columns of your content blocks but that won't really work if you are adding content dynamically.

The most common way to achieve what you want is to use a jQuery plugin called Masonry.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.